# SaltStack - using mine in pillar to dynamically build list of host names based on grain match

Tags: salt-stack

I'm having trouble using the salt mine in a pillar to dynamically create a list of hosts based on a grain value match. I don't get any error, I get no output for all hosts. Actually, I can't get any output for mine from the pillar at all even when using the example from the salt docs. I know it isn't an issue with my top file, because I can access all of the other pillar values. My test minion's mine.interval is set to 5. I've refreshed pillar data, and ran mine.update.

Here's an example of my pillar:

```
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs: []
  grains.item:
    - host
    - role
```

My template file that access the mine functions:

```
#I know this is writing the same list for each match, I'm just doing this for testing and I'll concat the results into a string when I know it works:
    {% for host in salt['mine.get']('roles:web', 'grains.items:host', expr_form='grain') | dictsort() %}
        serverList= {{ host }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Output from CLI:

```
salt "server.domain.com" mine.get "*" "*"
server.domain.com:
    ----------
```

How do I get this to work? I get no errors, no output, it just runs smoothly, but nothing is written in the file and I get nothing from the command line. My goal here is to be able to dynamically build a list of servers that match a specific grain to set a configuration value in a config template. Am I down the wrong path here, is there a better way?

Comment: have you run   `salt \* saltutil.refresh_pillar` ?

Comment: Yes - salt "*" saltutil.refresh_pillar, but I tried your syntax as well. Same output and nothing is being picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Utah_Dave, thanks so much for the help both here and in IRC.

Posting this as an answer so anyone else searching for this gets a good example...

pillar:

```
mine_functions:
  grains.items: []
```

template file:

```
  {% set ft_hosts = [] %}
  {% for grain_vals in salt['mine.get']('role:ps:ft:True', 'grains.items', expr_form='grain').items() %}
    {% do ft_hosts.append(grain_vals[1]['host']) %}
  {% endfor %}

  ft.ps.server.hosts={{ ft_hosts|join('|') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `mine.get` directly in your sls file to get that list of hosts. I don't think there's any need to pass that through pillar data.

Comment: Do you mean setting the mine_functions directly in the grains file on the minion(s) instead of via the pillar? I was hoping to use pillar so I didn't have to add it to the individual grains and could instead apply via pillar/top file matching.

Comment: OK, I think I'm confused as to what you're trying to do here.

Can you give a clearer explanation of what your desired result is?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to dynamically populate a list of host names in a managed file template. In the template I want to be able to find all other minions that match a specific grain value, and list the host grain value for each matching minion. Example, I want to find all minions that match a grain value of 'role: serverX', and list the 'host' value from the grains for each minion that matches 'role: serverX' to dynamically populate a property in a config file like 'serverX_hosts: host1|host2|host3|host4|host5'.